# Use BOX token from v1 to v2 API to get new tokens

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to use the old `access_token` saved somewhere from version 1 and use it to get new tokens in the version 2 API? We know that `access_token` on v1 takes forever and is limited in v2.

I'm asking if this is possible because we have a bunch of users and we don't want to make them have an access to the app again. All of them will not want to do this again.

In short I want a **silent upgrade** and don't want to bother them by saying, "You have to grant the app again in order to get a new access".

I hope you guys understand me. Hope someone will sort this out. If it's not possible, any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no silent upgrade path for access tokens. Your users *must* reauthorize your application. :\